# Undefined Offset: 1 laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, undefined, laravel-6

i wanna update the data of categories on multilevel choose item, but i had a problem, i can edit the categories without choose a parent, but i can't edit the categories when i choose a parent. then its showing a error called undefined offset:1 and here the trace error

```
Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError
   
C:\laragon\www\oesingcoffee\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Concerns\ValidatesAttributes.php:874
```

this is validates attrib in laravel framework

```
protected function getExtraConditions(array $segments)
{
$extra = [];
$count = count($segments);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i += 2) {
$extra[$segments[$i]] = $segments[$i + 1];  //this is the 874 line
}
return $extra;
}
```

this is the CategoryRequest class

```
class CategoryRequest extends FormRequest
{
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

public function rules()
{
    $parentId = (int) $this->get('parent_id');
    $id = (int) $this->get('id');

    if($this->method() == 'PUT'){
        if($parentId > 0){
            $name = 'required|unique:categories,name,'.$id.'id,parent_id,'.$parentId;         
        }else{
            $name = 'required|unique:categories,name,'.$id;
        }

        $slug = 'unique:categories,slug,'.$id;

    }else{
        $name = 'required|unique:categories,name,NULL,id,parent_id,'.$parentId;
        $slug = 'unique:categories,slug';
    }  

    return [
        'name' => $name,
        'slug' => $slug,
    ];
}
}
```

this is my controller to update the data

```
public function update(CategoryRequest $request, $id)
{
    $params = $request->except('_token');
    $params['slug'] = Str::slug($params['name']);
    $params['parent_id'] = (int)$params['parent_id'];

    $category = Category::findOrFail($id);
    if ($category->update($params)) {
        Session::flash('success', 'Category has been updated.');      
    }

    return redirect('admin/categories');   
}
```

this the view form

```
@extends('admin.layout')

@section('content')

@php
   $formTitle = !empty($category) ? 'Update' : 'New'    
@endphp

<div class="content">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="card card-default">
            <div class="card-header card-header-border-bottom">
                    <h2>{{ $formTitle }} Category</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                @include('admin.partials.flash', ['$errors' => $errors])
                @if (!empty($category))
                    {!! Form::model($category, ['url' => ['admin/categories', $category->id], 'method' => 'PUT']) !!}
                    {!! Form::hidden('id') !!}
                @else
                    {!! Form::open(['url' => 'admin/categories']) !!}
                @endif
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('name', 'Name') !!}
                        {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'category name']) !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('parent_id', 'Parent') !!}
                        {!! General::selectMultiLevel('parent_id', $categories, ['class' => 'form-control', 'selected' => !empty(old('parent_id')) ? old('parent_id') : !empty($category['parent_id']) ? $category['parent_id'] : '', 'placeholder' => '-- Choose Category --']) !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-footer pt-5 border-top">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-default">Save</button>
                        <a href="{{ url('admin/categories') }}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-default">Back</a>
                    </div>
                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

@endSection

this is the migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->bigInteger('parent_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

this is the edit method in controller

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $category = Category::findOrFail($id);
    $categories = Category::orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();

    $this->data['categories'] = $categories->toArray();
    $this->data['category'] = $category;
    return view('admin.categories.form', $this->data);
}
```

Comment: `ValidatesAttributes.php:874` It seems to be more likely in your **CategoryRequest** file can you edit your question with this file ?

Comment: I have edited it again sir

Comment: Thanks, but I meant your `CategoryRequest.php`

Comment: oops sorry i missed sir, i have edit it again now sir

Answer (score 0):

you should try save() method.

```
public function update(CategoryRequest $request, $id)
{
    $params = $request->except('_token');
    $params['slug'] = Str::slug($params['name']);
    $params['parent_id'] = (int)$params['parent_id'];

    $category = Category::findOrFail($id);
    if ($category->save()) {
        Session::flash('success', 'Category has been updated.');      
    }

    return redirect('admin/categories');   
}
```

Replace with above one.

Comment: please check your params.dd($request->all())

Comment: if I edit the category without selecting the category parent, the function $params.dd ($ request-> all ()); it works, but if I choose the category parent the function doesn't work sir

Comment: where did you place dd ($ request-> all ()) in your function?you should place it top of the function so that you can check that is params are available in request or not.on that basis you can get them.

Comment: i place it on top of the function sir, and still doesnt worked

Comment: public function update(CategoryRequest $request, $id)
        {
        $params.dd($request->all());
        $params = $request->except('_token');
        $params['slug'] = Str::slug($params['name']);
        $params['parent_id'] = (int)$params['parent_id'];
        
        $category = Category::findOrFail($id);
        if ($category->update($params)) {
            Session::flash('success', 'Category has been updated.');      
        }

        // $params.dd($request->all());
        return redirect('admin/categories');
    
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
public function update(CategoryRequest $request, $id)
{
    $params = $request->except('_token');
    $category = Category::findOrFail($id);
    $category->slug = Str::slug($params['name']);
    $category->parent_id = (int)$params['parent_id'];
    $category->save();
    Session::flash('success', 'Category has been updated.');

    return redirect('admin/categories');   
}
```

Comment: its still undefined offset:1 sir

Comment: `$params = $request->except('_token');` `dd($params); ` Check and show me `dd($params);` result

Comment: array:4 [▼
  "_method" => "PUT"
  "id" => "1"
  "name" => "Cemilan"
  "parent_id" => null
]

this worked when i didnt choose the parent category

Comment: Check `{{ dd($categories) }}` in your view file  and  show me result

Comment: array:5 [▼
  0 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "Cemilan"
   "slug" => "cemilan"
   "parent_id" => 0
    "created_at" => null
    "updated_at" => "2020-08-12 10:13:04"
  ]
  1 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 13
    "name" => "Gorengan"
    "slug" => "gorengan"
    "parent_id" => 1
    "created_at" => "2020-08-16 06:51:14"
    "updated_at" => "2020-08-16 06:51:14"
  ]
  2 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 12
    "name" => "Kopi Onta jawa"
    "slug" => "kopi-onta-jawa"
    "parent_id" => 4
    "created_at" => "2020-08-16 06:51:00"
    "updated_at" => "2020-08-16 06:51:00"
  ]

Comment: Can you show me your migration and public edit($id) in your controller?

Comment: Change **edit()** in your controller  
`$cats = [];
foreach($categories as $category){
   $cats[$category->id] = $category->name;
}

return view('admin.categories.form', [
 'categories' => $cats
]);`

Comment: then the error turn into Illegal string offset 'parent_id' sir

Comment: i edited again the $table->bigInteger('parent_id')->nullable; then, the error illegal string offset 'parent_id' is gone but the error turn to undefined offset:1 again

Comment: Sorry for mistake . Please change `$table->bigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();`  instead of `$table->bigInteger('parent_id')->nullable;`

Comment: its still undefined offset:1 sir ;'(

Comment: Remove `public function rules(){}` in your CategoryRequest class.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is inyour validation rule (specifically in your unique rule). May I suggest something else ?

I don't have the environment to test it right but now, so it may have some tweak to do.

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

...

public function rules()
{
    $name = [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('categories')->where(function ($query) {
            return $query->where('name', $this->name)
                         ->where('parent_id', $this->parent_id);
        })->ignore($this->id, 'id'),
    ];

    $slug = [
        Rule::unique('categories', 'slug')->ignore($this->id, 'id'),
    ];

    return [
        'name' => $name,
        'slug' => $slug,
    ];
}
```